# Querying Facebook Status Updates of a profile

Tags: facebook, updates, status

I have a website that query Facebook graphApi and get the available public data of pages.

I have some profiles, where graphApi does not return any data i.e. post/status data marked public on profile.

Even when I try to visit profile manually i.e. by typing url in IE -  https://www.facebook.com/ndalloul, it redirects me to Facebook login page.

But when I do it manually i.e. login to my Facebook Account and try to view the profile Ex:https://www.facebook.com/ndalloul shows me the data marked as public.

How to get this data from Facebook using API or Library?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which access token are you using?

Comment: Im generating it on the fly...by passing consumer key n secret values of app

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that Facebook is switching to the Graph API 2.0, you should not get any kind of redirect to login if you use your app access tokens and talk to the graph via cURL 8ro qeuivalent) .

The endpoint to get public statuses from fan pages, is `page_id/feed/` You need an access token from an app with with `read_stream` permission and only those who grant you that permission will show the latest posts. More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed) 
You may now have to be approved by facebook to read the stream, by the way.

Comment: You're looking for something like this, I assume http://niclarossini.com/tutorials/ (select "FB search engine", or even  "Facebook Feed")